# How do i remove GNOME from ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I have installed **Ubuntu 13.04** with **GNOME.**
Now i want to **remove** it completely and i want the **classic Ubuntu 13.04.**

Comment: Are you talking about Gnome?

Comment: yeah sorry i am talking about gnome and i have gnome 3.8

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which particular packages you installed, but with Synaptic you should be able to remove them all. Open it and select "Installed", then use the filter to search for the genome packages. Select all of them (you can confirm you have the correct set in [this list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=genome&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all)), right click and select "Mark for removal", finally click "Apply".

Comment: yeah sorry i am talking about gnome and i have gnome 3.8

Comment: Then just do the same but insert "gnome" in the filter instead of "genome".